# Why isn't RandomSearchCV returning the optimum parameters for the XGBoost Model, and how can I avoid Overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, boosting, overfitting, hyperparameter

I have a dataset for energy consumer customers and binary target variables with which I want to predict the churn for the customers. 
**Counts of target values**

1. Not Churn 0: 14153
2. Churn 1: 1520

I have trained XGBoost model with tree different strategies, but unfortunately model overfit the training dataset

1. I split the data into 80/20 and trained the XGBoost model with the following parameters

```
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
        learning_rate = 0.1,
        max_depth = 6,
        n_estimators = 500,
        n_jobs = -1,
        min_child_weight = 9
)

Result:
Accuracy:  0.9132431742791528
Precision:  0.7323943661971831
Recall:  0.13941018766756033
AUC Test: 0.709404       
AUC Train: 0.989078
```

2. Same model but with StratifiedKFold

```
StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=13, shuffle=True)
AUC Train: 0.986
AUC Test: 0.712
```

--- **UPDATED TEXT** 
3. Same Model but with additional parameters to add complexity

```
parameters = {'subsample': 0.8,
 'scale_pos_weight': 1,
 'n_estimates': 1100,
 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'max_depth': 12,
 'learning_rate': 0.01,
 'gamma': 4.0,
 'colsample_bytree': 0.60}

AUC Train: 0.7238 
AUC Test: 0.6568
```

The Question here is following

1. obviously, the model overfits the training example. How can I reduce the overfitting? I was reading the article that adding more parameters to the model would probably do that, but how can I select parameters? this would be the hit and trial method. What is the best way?
2. I got the best parameters from RandomSearchCV for the third model, but with those values, I got AUC-test and Train 0.5 both, which is strange because it is supposed to give me the best parameters and the best AUC score. After getting unsuccessful results, I updated parameter values on my own and didn't use the Best_parameters_ given by Random CV. Why isn't it providing me with the best parameters?

Comment: Have you tried using `best_estimator_` in Random CV object? It should be the fitted version, does it give 0.5 AUC as well?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your third reported scores and the 0.5 from the same parameters.

Comment: Yes @gunes , as I mentioned, I used the RandomCV, and passed the ```best_estimators_``` to the XGboost model, it gave me 0.5 AUC. Of course, that was not the AUC I wanted, I tuned some parameters own my own to get the desired AUC's

Comment: @BenReiniger, I apologize If I wasn't clear. I updated the above description.
Actually, what I was trying to convey, I used Random CV to get ```best_parameters_``` for my xgboost model, but unfortunately, with those parameters, I got 0.5 Test and Train ACUs, which was unexpected. I didn't use those ```best_parameters_``` for my model, but, tuned on my own some values with the hit and trial method to get the best validations. I got AUC Train: 0.7238 and AUC Test: 0.6568, which is quite good than 0.5.

Comment: @BenReiniger The question is, ```best_parameters__``` didn't work for me here, why were the random Cv unable to give me these parameters?

Comment: You should provide details about the random search (space definition and #tested points). // How can the search have selected parameters that give 0.5 AUC on test? You're refitting somewhere?